# Cannot access web services running locally

Tags: java, web-services

Hi I am new to JAVA web services. Problem is that I cannot hit web services running in my local machine. Though web service is running, while I am hitting like following

```
curl -X GET -H "Authorization: Basic Ypri" -H "Accept: application/xml" -H "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "Cache-Control: no-cache" -H "Postman-Token: xxxx" "http://localhost:7093/ws/xyz/findComponent/?login=abc@yahoo.com"
```

, I am getting following response:

```
<ns1:XMLFault xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">
<ns1:faultstring xmlns:ns1="http://cxf.apache.org/bindings/xformat">java.nio.channels.UnresolvedAddressException</ns1:faultstring>
```

In my /etc/hosts following mappings are there for localhost:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
```

I have no clue regrading that.

Comment: Which client are you using? Which URL are you accessing?

Comment: I am using postman, and this problem I think is not dependent on client, I have tried the same with curl command from terminal, then also the same issue is coming.

Comment: instead of localhost put your IP, you ll get your IP using ipconfig command on console.

Comment: Unless you post specifics of what you tried and how, it would be really difficult for anyone to give any suggestions/answers.

Comment: I  have installed java 8. is it may be because of that?